# Customizing the creation of anonymous sequences in AutoFixture

Tags: autofixture

Using [anonymous sequences](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/11/AnonymousSequencesWithAutoFixture/), I can create sequences of objects when I don't care so much about how many, or what type of sequence it is:

```
public class Foo { public string Bar { get; set; } }

var fixture = new Fixture();
var foos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>();
```

Is there some way I can customize the creation of such sequences, and e.g. set a property on each item in the collection, in a way that considers the entire collection at once, and not just one item at a time?

For example, is there a way to achieve the following?

```
public interface ISortable
{
    int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : ISortable
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

var fixture = new Fixture();

// TODO: Customize the fixture here

var foos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>();

// foos now have sort-order set to e.g. a multiple of their index
// in the list, so if three items, they have sort order 0, 10, 20.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I handed over control of AutoFixture, so my information could be out of date, but I don't think there's any feature like that. What I usually do in cases like that is that use normal code to configure what AutoFixture generates. In this particular case, you can use a zip to achieve the desired result; prototype:

```
[Fact]
public void SetSortOrderOnFoos()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var foos = fixture
        .CreateMany<Foo>()
        .Zip(
            Enumerable.Range(0, fixture.RepeatCount),
            (f, i) => { f.SortOrder = i * 10; return f; });

    Assert.Equal(3, foos.Count());
    Assert.Equal( 0, foos.ElementAt(0).SortOrder);
    Assert.Equal(10, foos.ElementAt(1).SortOrder);
    Assert.Equal(20, foos.ElementAt(2).SortOrder);
}
```

This test isn't robust, but I hope it communicates the core idea.

Comment: Thanks! Although it doesn't really solve my problem - I still have to remember to do this any time I want a collection of `Foo`s - it shows a clean enough way to do it, which I can probably abstract away some other way (e.g. with an extension method on `IFixture`).

Comment: @TomasLycken Isn't it an exotic problem? In the general case, why not implement `IComparable<T>` and sort the generated collection?

Comment: It is a quite exotic problem, yes. In this case, it's a system that sorts a lot of stuff quite arbitrarily, with the sort order persisted in the database, and the customer wants to be able to insert new rows "between" the old ones, without having to update the sort orders of the entire list. Admittedly, this is not something I expected AutoFixture to support out-of-the-box :) However, generally being able to customize collections of items seems to me to be something that's not so exotic. OTOH, it's not so difficult to work around either :)

Comment: @TomasLycken People sometimes have quite specific wishes about how AutoFixture could do something exotic while it creates objects. As a library author, I couldn't predict what people would want to do, so I focused on providing an API that solved the problems that I was fairly sure that people would have (typically because I had them myself). For other things, I didn't want to invent 'half of Common Lisp' when I didn't know what would be required. For collections, for example, C# already has a fine API. It's called LINQ. It's better than anything I could come up with for AutoFixture.

Comment: @TomasLycken To be clear, though, [I no longer decide anything regarding AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/703), so it's possible that the current maintainers take a different view on this.

Comment: I know, and I sincerely appreciate your efforts :)